# Recognize isolated words instead of words combinations

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am trying to improve accuracy of pocketsphinx using a dictionary..
I gave a list of words like

```
 apple
 ball
 bottle
```

Many a time I noticed that it gives me a combination of these words as the result

```
 apple ball
 bottle ball etc
```

Is there a way to solve this problem? Any flag that says output only one of these words and not a combination.

Comment: Can you post the grammar?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: For anything but trivial use, you need to specify a grammar. This will define that you are looking for a single word. You can also specify weighting for more common words.

Comment: I'm using the following link to get the .dic and .lm files

Comment: speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html

Comment: Is grammar same as language model. If so how do I specify the weight?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grammar like this instead of a language model

```
 #JSGF V1.0; 
 grammar test;
 public <result> = apple | ball | book;
```

For more details see cmusphinx language model tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm